# How to use hover rule on focused element?

Tags: jquery, css

This is my code:

```
.metismenu li a:hover{ background:#112542;} /*would not affect when it has focus*/
.metismenu li a:focus{ background:inherit;}
```

When I have clicked on `a` it's `background-color` is changing to `inherit` and I am hovering mouse again on it, it's `background-color` is not changing to `#112542` until I am not clicking anywhere outside `a` (*Because it still has the focus and `background-color: inherit;`*). Is there any solution that I can change it's `background-color` without clicking outside it and hovering mouse again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `:focus:hover` state, like in this example : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbsgf8wh/4/)

```
.metismenu li a:focus:hover{ background:yellow;}
```

```css
.metismenu li a:hover{ background:#112542;}
.metismenu li a:focus{ background:inherit;}
.metismenu li a:focus:hover{ background:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="metismenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#!">link test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In this example, when you click `a` the background is `#112542` because you are hovering it while clicking it. If you move your cursor without clicking outside, it still have the focus (and the inherit background) and if you hover it without clicking outside, you can see the `:focus:hover` effect
I've changed the color in my example to show the difference